# Spring Reactor List<Mono<Int>> sequence to Mono<List<Int>>

Tags: spring, reactor

The objective is to sequence a `List<Mono<Int>>` to `Mono<List<Int>>`. The body of `flatMap` is doing so using `Mono.block()` in the Kotlin code snippet. Is there a much better way than this if I want to keep `Mono<List<Int>>` instead of a `Flux<Int>`? Thanks

```
    fun foo(i: Int): Mono<Int> = Mono.just(i)

    fun doubleUp(i: Int): List<Mono<Int>> {
        return listOf(Mono.just(i * 2), Mono.just((i + 1) * 2), Mono.just((i + 2) * 2))
    }

    val listOfMono: Mono<ArrayList<Int>> = foo(10).flatMap {
        val xs = doubleUp(it)
        val ys = ArrayList<Int>()
        xs.forEach{ys.add(it.block())}  // Mono.block()
        Mono.just(ys)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val listOfMono: Mono<List<Mono<Int>>> = foo(10).flatMap {
    Flux.fromIterable(doubleUp(it))
            .collectList()
}
```

You don't have way to skip a `Flux`, but it is an internal stuff anyway.